# How to get full image from div that containing amchart4 and convert into pdf to be downloaded?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, jspdf, html2canvas, amcharts4

I'm trying to convert a div that contains amcharts4 into images and put it to pdf and download it.

But when it is saved into pdf, the amcharts4 is cropped, as in pictures

[image]

this is the actual div

[image]

nb: even through i'm using metronic template, i'm not using amcharts4 from metronic's one

this is my code when print button is triggered

```
const filename  = 'ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf';

        html2canvas(document.querySelector('.m-content')).then(canvas => {
            let pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'JPEG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
            pdf.save(filename);
        });
```

and this the external script that i included

```
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amCharts have their own builtin chart to PDF export feature. Please [check the basics here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/).

It's possible to have multiple charts added to the same PDF file as [shown here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/generating-multi-content-pdf-export/).

Now if you really need to use `html2canvas` you could likely still get the image using the export feature and then add the Base64 image to your file:

```
var imgData = chart.exporting.getImage("png");
```